# TypeError: dispatch is not a function error when calling dispatch()

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I tried to call this action using `useDispatch` hook and it gives me this warning. I'm Using `Redux-thunk` as well.

ProductScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Loader from "../Loader";
import Product from "../parts/Products";
import { listProducts } from "../../store/actions/productActions";


import "../../App.css";
import "../parts/Products.css";




function ProductScreen()  {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productList = useSelector((state)=> state.productList);
  const { loading, products } = productList;

  useEffect(()=> {
    dispatch(listProducts())
  },[dispatch]);

  return(
    <div>
      {loading ? (<Loader />) :(
        <div className="row center">
          {products.map((product)=>(
            <Product key={product._id} product={product} />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );

  
}

export default ProductScreen;
```

ProductActions.js

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import {
    PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL 
} from '../constants/ProductConstant.js';

export const listProducts = ()=> async (dispatch)=> {
    dispatch({
        type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
      });
      try {
        const { data } = await Axios.get('/api/products');
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message });
      }
}

export const detailsProduct = (productId) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
      payload: productId,
    });
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/products/${productId}`);
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL, payload: error.response && error.response.data.message ?
          error.response.data.message : error.message,
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: So the awesome thing about TypeScript is that I can use a type annotation. That is going to be what ensures that I only call dispatch with a properly typed action object. So it would look like so: `export const listProducts = () => {
 return async (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) => {
  dispatch({ type: ActionType.PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST });

  try {
   const { data } = await axios.get(‘/api/products’);
  } catch (error) {

  }
 };
};`

Answer (score 1):

Here I was able to solve the Issue with removing the `compose` component from here, So by making,
compose need to be used if you are running the function from right to left.

```
const store = createStore(reducers,initialState, applyMiddleware((thunk)));
```